# Express callback order issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I have the following issue the logic inside the Promise chain is working but I'm setting the formValues variable after rendering the form so mustache template input fields are not receiving the values.
Is there any solution so that I don't have to rethink/rewire the whole route handler "/nst" ?

Many thanks!

```
router.post('/nst', (req, res, next,) => {    
    // res.json({ msg: 'New ST reached!' });
    next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('first');
    try {
        let { user, pass, email, } = req.body;
        fetch(`${apisList[0].getTokenURL_new_ST}${client_id}=${secret}&${username}=${user}&${password}=${pass}&response_type=token`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => setToken(actionName, email, user, res.access_token))
            .then(res => getAgentNumber(res))
            .then(res => setString(secret, JSON.parse(res.UIResult.Data).AgentNumber, email))            
            .then(res => {formValues = res; console.log('RES in CHAIN',res)})              
            .catch(e => console.log(`error in chain ${e}`))
    }
    catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
    next()
},function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('form')
    // console.log('middle');
    
    next()
})
router.get('/form', (req,res,next) => {    
    res.render('SSRForm.html',formValues)
})
```

Comment: Don't call `next()` immediately. Do it when the promise chain is done. (Same for error handling).

Comment: please transfer your code and use `async/await` will make your code more readable and testable too